# How to popup Image using codes UWP

Tags: c#, image, uwp, popup

I have an app load pictures from the internet I want to add a popup event to the image so the user can view the image by click on it !
I've try a lot of things to do that all that I can found is to resize the image or just view a content dialog with a text on it !
Here's my code :

```
    private static void view_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Viewbox image = sender as Viewbox;

        Panel parent = image.Parent as Panel;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            image.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 0.5, ScaleY = 0.5 };
            parent.Children.Remove(image);
            parent.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            parent.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            parent.Children.Add(new Popup() { Child = image, IsOpen = true, Tag = parent });
        }
        else
        {
            Popup popup = image.Parent as Popup;
            popup.Child = null;
            Panel panel = popup.Tag as Panel;
            image.RenderTransform = null;
            panel.Children.Add(image);
        }
    }
```

I want it to look like that I want to keep my old image in the same place and create a new grid that have the same image like this image you can view it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3EKH.png)

I can't use the xaml file  because my image load from the web by code using a dll file !

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the image doesn't display is because you don't add an [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) control into the ViewBox to display the image content, you can try the following code to display an image in the popup.

```
private void Viewbox_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Viewbox image = sender as Viewbox;
    Image imageControl = new Image() { Width = 500, Height = 500 };
    Uri uri = new Uri("Your image URL");
    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
    imageControl.Source = source;
    image.Child = imageControl;
    Panel parent = image.Parent as Panel;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        image.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 0.5, ScaleY = 0.5 };
        parent.Children.Remove(image);
        parent.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        parent.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        parent.Children.Add(new Popup() { Child = image, IsOpen = true, Tag=parent});
    }
    else
    {
        Popup popup = image.Parent as Popup;
        popup.Child = null;
        Panel panel = popup.Tag as Panel;
        image.RenderTransform = null;
        panel.Children.Add(image);
    }
}
```

By the way, please notice that the [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) is a control that displays content on top of existing content, within the bounds of the application window, and pay attention to the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup#remarks) part,

> Do not use a Popup if a Flyout, MenuFlyout, ToolTip or ContentDialog (MessageDialog for a Windows 8 app) is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't want it to be like my code i want it to view as a popup image like with the content dialog and I want to make the background black when I click , this code just rescale it ! and my code works fine with this hope you help me !

Comment: @louay Do you want the background page  to be black when the popup shows? If so,  you can try to set the page's background to be black when you click it. You can show me the similar effect you want if this is not what you want?

Comment: I want to create a new grid that have a new image I want to keep my old one and generate a new one Like this ex in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3EKH.png)